# Too many open files occured when cassandra snapshot

Tags: java, backup, cassandra, snapshot

java error occured when I try to cassandra snapshot.

root@cassandra mytest]# /usr/local/apache-cassandra-1.1.7/bin/nodetool -h localhost mytest

---

[image]

so, I added to /etc/security/limits.conf

follow this: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/troubleshooting/index#java-reports-an-error-saying-there-are-too-many-open-files

- soft nofile 32768
- hard nofile 32768
- root soft nofile 32768
- root hard nofile 32768
- soft memlock unlimited
- hard memlock unlimited
- root soft memlock unlimited
- root hard memlock unlimited
- soft as unlimited
- hard as unlimited
- root soft as unlimited
- root hard as unlimited

but still error occured.

please hel me.

I use CentOS.

ps.
I following this:
On CentOS, RHEL, OEL Sysems, change the system limits from 1024 to 10240 in /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf and then start a new shell for these changes to take effect.
*  soft  nproc  10240

but i can't find "/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf"

i'm sorry. i'm poor at english.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **limits.conf**, you need to do the following:

Edit **/etc/pam.d/login**, adding the line:

```
session required /lib/security/pam_limits.so
```

please try it and let me know of the result.

Comment: it's still occured same error.

"session required /lib/security/pam_limits.so" 
add this line, what should i do?

Comment: of course you should stop your application, log out, and log in again for your changes to take effect, and then start your application again. of course about RHEL I know it works, however for CentOs I'm not sure, a system restart might be necessary. anyway let me know of results. :)

Comment: I'm sorry. my cassandra's data reomved all. my mistake.
so I can't test "too many file open" error. T.T
If i see same error, I will retry your advice.